# Code signing a new application, will windows and chrome consider it safe?

Tags: google-chrome, delphi, code-signing, smartscreen

I'm developing an application in Delphi that does connect to an online API and fetches data periodically.

It's installer is created by Innosetup.

The problem is that whenever a new user downloads it from the website, chrome will tell them that it is potentially unsafe, and they have to take additional steps so that the file will be kept after downloading.

Then after this when they start the installer Windows 10 Smartscreen will tell them that the software is not used by many people and might be dangerous, here they also have to take extra steps to start it up.

Lots of potential users are not going through this process, and I considered purchasing a code signing cert from StartSSL.

But first I wanted to ask you whether this will solve my problems I mentioned?

If not then what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it very likely that code signing will be enough for these apps to trust your installer

Comment: @Jerry: The only ones that can do that are diamond mods, and they typically only do so in response to a flag of some sort (which sometimes is by a user asking a mod to clean up comment clutter). For the most part, you have to clean up your own mess here. :-)

Comment: StartSSL's free certificate is not for use for code signing. You'll have to purchase at least the StartSSL Verified object code signing certificate, but it's not going to help with SmartScreen - it's based on the number of people that have downloaded the app via Internet Explorer, according to Microsoft's [SmartScreen Filter FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17443/windows-internet-explorer-smartscreen-filter-faq). Unless your app becomes very popular among users of IE, or enough people tell MS it's safe, you'll probably have to live with that issue.

Comment: @Ken Signing will help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/03/22/smartscreen-application-reputation-building-reputation/

Comment: To clarify I'm not talking about the smartscreen in IE, but in WIndows 10, this is a full screen popup, almost like the UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Unicode version of Inno Setup if you're not already. Installers created with the non-Unicode version of Inno Setup are frequently flagged as malware by many anti-virus/anti-malware programs. Also when code-signing make sure you have an SHA-256 certificate as Windows 10 no longer treats EXEs signed with older SHA-1 certificates as signed.

Comment: I recall hearing that updates to even older versions of Windows will also get this change?

Comment: You can also dual sign with both sha1 and sha256